# Update one table conditionally based on values of another

Tags: php, mysql

Hi, I have 2 tables: `user_badges`, and `badges` table, the following is `user_badges` table data:

```
id | user_id | badge_id | points_earned | badges_awarded |
 1    2324        0             5               0
```

If the user meets the minimum required points, i.e. 5 from the `badges` table, SQL will update the above as:

```
id | user_id | badge_id | points_earned | badges_awarded |
 1    2324        1             5               1
```

If, in future, there is new point registered for the same user, `user_table` badges will add a new row as follows:

```
 id | user_id | badge_id | points_earned | badges_awarded |
  1    2324        1             5               1
  2    2324        0             7               0
```

---

### The above issue has been solved

---

This is `badges` table:

```
badge_id | badge_name | required_points
   1           new          5
   2           adv          10
```

---

### Below is what I need

---

The problems is I need a query to compare the `user_badges` table to the `badges` table, provided that the query must know if the badges have been awarded before or not.

I am using this for Zend applications, need a solution for this problem...

Comment: Based on what you're trying to do, it doesn't seem like you have the right database design. To me, it seems like you're trying to find the most advanced badge based on a user's points. For this, all you need is the `badges` table and user-points stored in a column in your `users` table, then you can just do a query to figure out all badges with required points less than the user's current points to list that user's badges.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand the question. Any chance you can explain again? What exactly do you want to compare? Also, please provide with table data which has matching values.

Comment: Anyway you could extend the deadline? it says ending in 3 hours... but, am in office, I could answer that but, after going home... Any chance of extension?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, first you need to get the users for whom badges are not yet awarded before, then using `correlated subquery` you need to update table `user_badges` with corresponding highest valid `badges_id` from `badges` tables.

```
UPDATE user_badges a
       INNER JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT user_id, SUM(badges_awarded) AS total_badges_awarded
                  FROM user_badges
                  GROUP BY user_id
                 ) b
             ON a.user_id = b.user_id
                AND b.total_badges_awarded = 0
SET a.badge_id = (@var_badges_awarded_flag:= (IFNULL((
                             SELECT c.badge_id
                             FROM badges c
                             WHERE a.points_earned > c.required_points
                             ORDER BY c.required_points DESC
                             LIMIT 1
                            ), 0))),
    a.badges_awarded = a.badges_awarded + IF(@var_badges_awarded_flag > 0, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some SQL logic that will get you all users and the next badge each one can earn:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_badges
JOIN badges
ON badges.badge_id = (user_badges.badge_id + 1)
```

Then you can cycle through each user and determine if their badge needs to get updated with PHP:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) // where result is the result from running the above query
{
    if ($row["points_earned"] >= $row["required_points"]) // enough points for next badge, update badges
    {
        mysqli_query("UPDATE user_badges SET badge_id = badge_id + 1, badges_awarded = badges_awarded + 1 WHERE user_id = ".$row['user_id']);
    }
}
```

This is just some example SQL/PHP code to get you started.  You can query whichever rows you want, check them in PHP, and update them if necessary at any time you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping track of the points earned in the `user_badges` table I would keep them elsewhere, either inside the `users` table or in a separate table `user_points`. This makes it easier to update one's points by just a simple `UPDATE ... SET earned_points = earned_points + :points`.

Next, I would simplify the `user_badges` table to:

```
user_id | badge_id
```

Use a spanning `UNIQUE` index to make sure a user cannot have more than one of each badge.

Finally, updating the `user_badges` table can be performed as a background task (cron, etc.) using two steps:

1. Identify which badges have been earned using `points_earned >= required_points`.
2. Insert new badges into `user_badges` using `INSERT IGNORE INTO user_badges ...`; this makes sure only new badges are added and existing ones aren't overwritten.